# how to get the google map url of my current location in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, geolocation, location

I'm trying to get the exact URL of my current location showing my gps location as a marker on the map.

[image]

Comment: Show some effort first.

Comment: Read the google maps api documentation. Make some efforts at your end . Then share your code trials if you get stuck. Read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how to ask good question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a link in this format:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=36.26577,-92.54324
```

and add the `latitude` and `longitude` of your location in the place of `36.26577` and `-92.54324` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
 http://maps.google.com/?q=<lat>,<lng>
```

Use the above format, pass your values of lat and lng to the above URL format.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it with android Intent as.

```
String geoUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + <lat-long>;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUri));
startActivity(intent);
```

or simply URL

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + <lat-long>;
```